# How to position X button on top right of YouTube video?

Tags: html, css, iframe, position

I have a div called "stage" containing a YouTube video, and a div called "stageX" which would contain an X button (which I will later program to hide the video when clicked).

I'm trying to position the X to be at the top right of the YouTube video, and to maintain its position when the user zooms in and out of the page.

I set 'stage' as relative and 'stageX' as absolute, but this isn't working... What am I doing wrong here?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxdPoa

```
<section id="headerstage">
        <div id="stageX">X</div>
        <div id="stage">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/e-ORhEE9VVg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#body{
    color:black;
}
#stage{
    text-align:center;
    width:1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
}

#stageX{
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Don't use both absolute positioning and floating. Just use absolute positioning.

b) For the position to be relative to an element, the absolutely positioned element needs to be **inside** the relatively positioned element.

c) Absolute positioning works with the `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` CSS properties. So if you would like something to be at the top right corner of a containing element, you would do:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>X</div>
</div>
```